# Network request failed (It was working until today)

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing a react native app with expo and it was working everything perfectly, the app was almost finished and working all functionalities. I tested for last time Thursday and today, Monday I open my app and I see a error on my app "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError:

> Network request failed]"

which I am doing a fetch from a `url` that isn´t a localhost one, and I remember you was working fine until today. Can someone help me if there was any update by expo or anyone knows what happened to not working now but working before?